# chrome coverage report - is there any API to receive json file?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Lately i have discovered chrome coverage report that I find very useful. 
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/devtools-release-notes#coverage

The weakness of this tools is that it is single page scoped. But in version chrome 73 there is an option to generate json file for page that can be stored for further processing.

I would like to collect json data for multiple pages, than merge it and visualize in the context of single file (in my case stylesheet).

It would be great if I could receive json file directly through chrome (Extenstion?) API. So far i have found only this example: https://gist.github.com/krisselden/2487706bcbf37da26d4a89d0f74df768. But it seems to work only for browser remote mode.

Do you know is there any way to get coverage json report over chrome API?

Best regards
It Man.

Comment: Extensions can use `chrome.debugger` API to issue the same [RDP commands](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) used by that gist.

Comment: Thanks for this cue. I will try it inside extension.

Comment: Ok, I have implemented the proof of concept. I was able to read coverage data. Thanks for   help!

Comment: Consider adding an answer with the actual code or some parts of it.

Comment: @wOxxOm I'll try, but at the moment coverage data is not exactly what I've expected. Find no css info inside it, have to check other profiler options.

Comment: No luck with css, seems that Profiler.startPreciseCoverage returns only javascript coverage. Have any idea hot do read css coverage data?

Comment: Poking https://cs.chromium.org reveals devtools is using CSS.startRuleUsageTracking, you can also eavesdrop on devtools using its built-in [protocol monitor](https://umaar.com/dev-tips/166-protocol-monitor/).

Answer (score 2):

Heres what i got so far (snippets only):

1. Got extension template form https://extensionizr.com
2. Inside background.js script have placed this raw method:

```
    chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log(request.command);
        if (request.command === "getCoverage") {
            chrome.tabs.query(
                {currentWindow: true, active : true},
                function(tabArray){
                    var activeTab = tabArray[0];
                    console.log("tabid: " + activeTab.id)
                    chrome.debugger.attach( { tabId: activeTab.id }, "1.2", function() {
                        console.log("attached");
                        chrome.debugger.sendCommand( { tabId: activeTab.id }, "Profiler.enable", undefined, function(result) {
                            console.log("ProfilerStarted:" ,result);
                            chrome.debugger.sendCommand( { tabId: activeTab.id }, "Profiler.startPreciseCoverage", { callCount: true }, function(result) {
                                console.log("coverageStarted:" ,result);
                                setTimeout(function() {
                                    chrome.debugger.sendCommand( { tabId: activeTab.id }, "Profiler.takePreciseCoverage", undefined, function(response) {
                                        console.log(response.result);
                                    });
                                }, 4000)
                            });
                        });
                    });
                }
            );
        }
    });
```

3. Inside browser_action.js:

```
    document.getElementById("getCoverageSnapshot").addEventListener("click", function() {
        chrome.extension.sendMessage({
            command: "getCoverage"
        });             
    });
```

4. And in browse_action.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<button id="getCoverageSnapshot">Get Snapshot</button>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="/src/browser_action/browser_action.js"></script>
```

[image]

When button clicked Profiler.takePreciseCoverage result can be recieved inside background.js.

Still looking the way to receive css coverage data...